# Creating a promise with success / error for example like ajax

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to figure out how to make promises work with a success and error callback like for example in ajax.

I have the following promise:

```
  var promise = new Promise(function(success, error) {
      if (true) {
         success("Stuff worked!");
      }
      else {
          error(Error("It broke"));
      }
    });
  promise.then(function(result)
  {
      console.log(result);
  }, function(err)
  {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

I want it to work like this:

```
promise.success(function(response)
{
  console.log(response);
}).error(functin(err)
{
  console.log(err);
});
```

What am I suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success` and `error` are merely syntactic sugar that does the same as the following:

```
function CustomPromise(callback){
  this.promise = new Promise(callback);
}

// Success and error are merely shorthand functions 
CustomPromise.prototype.success = function(callback){
  this.promise.then(callback,null);
};

CustomPromise.prototype.error = function(callback){
  this.promise.then(null,callback);
}

// Expose the rest of the promise interface, especially `then` and `catch`
```

Note that I did not extend the native `Promise` prototype as it is bad practice.

I suggest you stick to `then(success,error)` though, as this has become the "standard" interface for promises. jQuery and several other libs, to some extent, follow this.

Comment: This was it, but remember to use `return this;` after the success/error function so u can chain them.

Comment: Native promises are not subclassable - this _will_ break in browsers in the near future since they do not implement the spec well - also note you should `.prototype = Object.create(Promise.prototype)` and call `Promise(this)` - again: this is all stuff the spec says native promises _should_ do but don't. Also I'm really not convinced that extending the native prototype of promises is such a bad idea but that's subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Promises simply use a different terminology, your `.success` and `.error` translate to `.then` and `.catch` on promises.

```
promise
    .then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

If you **really** want to (please don't), you can do something like this

```
Promise.prototype.success = Promise.prototype.success || Promise.prototype.then;
Promise.prototype.error = Promise.prototype.error || Promise.prototype.catch;
```

Comment: So how does $.post does it? any idea?

Comment: @DalaiLama jQuery uses a different (bad) kind of promises, that don't conform to the ECMAScript or the Promises A+ specs. I wouldn't take it as an example (or use it at all for that matter).

Comment: Ok its not only Jquery.

Take for example Angular $http post.
I still need to test it and for that I need to mock its behavior.
I am not going to use it on my code, I am going to test it.

Comment: @DalaiLama then use [the Angular mock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). As for how it defines them afaik all it does is `req.success = function(fn){ return req.then(function(res){ return res.data; }).then(fn); }` or something like that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I knew you'd come to rescue me if I added the [tag:promise] tag! :D